# How to find angle with $\tan(\alpha)$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to find this angle with $\tan(\alpha)$.
How should I start with the question?

Comment: try using angle between tangent and secsnt is equal to angle in alternate segment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the radius of the circle. Let $(R,0)$, $(x,y)$ and $(0,R)$ be the coordinates of the points belonging to the circle. Writing Pythagoras' theorem for the three right triangles that can be seen gives  :

$$\left\{\begin{eqnarray}
(a) \ \ &x^2+(y-R)^2&=&6^2\\
(b) \ \ &x^2+y^2&=&R^2\\
(c) \ \ &x^2+R^2&=&14^2
\end{eqnarray}\right.$$

From (c), one has $x^2=196-R^2$. Plugging this expression of $x^2$ in (a) and (b) gives a system of two equations with two unknowns $y$ and $R$ from which you should conclude that $y=8 \sqrt{2}, \ R=9 \sqrt{2}.$

Thus $x^2=196-R^2=196-162=34$; then $x=\sqrt{34}$.

Then plug the results into the following formula : $\tan \alpha = R/x$ whence :

$\alpha = \mathbb{atan}(R/x)=\mathbb{atan}(9 \sqrt{2}/\sqrt{34})=\mathbb{atan}(9/\sqrt{17}) \ \approx \ 1.1412$ (radians).

i.e., approx. $64$ degrees and a half.

Comment: I have a little improved my solution...

Answer (score 1):

define $\beta$ is the $\angle FCD$ in rogerl's answer.

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
     2 R \sin\beta &= 6 \\
 6 \cos \beta &= \sqrt{14^2 - R^2}
\end{aligned} \right.
$$

define $x = \cos^2\beta$

we can get $36x^2 - 232x + 187 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{17}{18}$

so $\sin\beta = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}$ and $R=9\sqrt{2}$

thus $\tan\alpha = \frac{R}{6\cos\beta} = \frac{9\sqrt{2}}{6\sqrt{\frac{17}{18}}} = \frac{9}{\sqrt{17}}$

Answer (score 0):

The task is to find $\tan\alpha$, you should favor a trigonometric approach.

Note that $R=14\sin\alpha$.

Denote the angle between the tangent and chord of 6cm with $\beta$.
Also note that if you draw lines from the center of the circle to both ends of the chord of 6cm, the angle between these two lines is $2\beta$ (the proof is elementary).

$$14\cos\alpha=6\cos\beta\tag{1}$$

$$2R\sin\frac{2\beta}{2}=2\times14\sin\alpha\sin\beta=6$$

$$28\sin\alpha\sin\beta=6\tag{2}$$

Try to solve $\alpha,\beta$ from (1),(2). For example, express $\cos\beta$ from (1) and $\sin\beta$ from (2). Square these two expressions and add, $\beta$ will disappear. You'll get a simple equation with angle $\alpha$ being the only unknown.

Answer (score 0):

In the diagram below, from the given data, we have $AC = AD = r$, $CD=6$, $CE=14$. We want to find $CA$ and $AE$. Call $a=AE$, $b=ED$. Then from Pythagoras,
$$r^2 + a^2 = 196,\quad a^2+b^2 = r^2,\quad a^2 + (r-b)^2 = 36.$$
Solve these equations to find $r$ and $a$.

[image]